# Go - Combining cmd.StdoutPipe and Cmd.StderrPipe

Tags: go, exec

I would like to execute a command in Go, and combining its stdout and stderr into one stream. I wrote this code, its read only from the stdout, but I don't know how to I combine it with the stderr:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "bufio"
)

func runCommand() {
    var (
        err error
    )

    cmdName := "docker"
    cmdArgs := []string{"build", "--no-cache=true", "--force-rm=true", "."}

    cmd := exec.Command(cmdName, cmdArgs...)

    cmdReader, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error creating StdoutPipe for Cmd", err)
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(cmdReader)
    go func() {
        for scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Printf("docker build out | %s\n", scanner.Text())
        }
    }()

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error starting Cmd", err)
    }

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error waiting for Cmd", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    runCommand()
}
```

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Why not do the same thing for stderr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function [`io.MultiReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiReader) to combine multiple readers into one:

```
outReader, err := cmd.StdoutReader()
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}

errReader, err := cmd.StderrReader()
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}

cmdReader := io.MultiReader(outReader, errReader)
```

Comment: This approach returns all output from stdout before returning any from stdin.

Answer (score 26):

To combine stdout and stderr to a single reader, assign a single pipe to Command.Stdout and Command.Stderr:

```
cmdReader, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
cmd.Stderr = cmd.Stdout
```

Comment: Alternatively, create a decicated pipe using `os.Pipe()` and then assign its write end to both `Stderr` and `Stdout` fields of your `cmd` instance. Then read from its read end.

Comment: @kostix The StdoutPipe method is easier to use because it [arranges to close the os.Pipe writer at Start() and the os.Pipe reader at Wait()](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/13f74db304fdf6dc6241485d6e6f3f6a0327633c/src/os/exec/exec.go#L512-L518).